# The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

The problem is when I run my app, it works fine. But when I refresh it, most of the time I get below msg.

> The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

**But the strange thing is that many times when I refresh my app it works  also.**

So ultimately I have a strange behavior of my app and unable to figure this out. 

**Sometimes it works sometimes doesn't...**

Any suggestion, can't come up with code???

***Note : I don't have complex structure or components yet but simple implementation.***

Comment: post the full error message or either portion of code or `my-app` component.

Comment: In IE11 - `Potentially unhandled rejection [2] The selector "micropuppy-app" did not match any elements` and In FF- 'EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements  BaseException@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:7351:21
..... ... ... .. and continue'

Comment: I've seen this couple of times - it's an IE issue, specifically how it loads scripts if I remember correctly. I'm afraid I don't know the fix for it, was long time ago, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sasxa, I m facing this problem in FF also. I don't know whats the problem. N feel helpless...

Answer (score 104):

This happened to me because I was importing my code in the `head` tag, so it was potentially running and attempting to bootstrap before the DOM was ready.

You can either move the script to the bottom of the `body` tag, or put the bootstrap code within an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `main.js` script inclusion in the plunker demos in the typescript documentation. Athough I do have the error.

Comment: I didn't get this error until I tried to bundle my compiled typescript files.

Comment: I faced the same issue while using webpack for module bundling.... and once i placed the script after .. body tag.. it's working...

Comment: I also only received this error once I bundled everything. Beware!

Comment: You can also attach it to the window.onload event: `window.onload = function(){
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}`

Comment: OMG I was banging my head on the wall for so long trying to figure this out and it was so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 74):

Angular 4: I had to change   `<app-root></app-root>` with   `<my-app></my-app>` in the index.html file

Comment: There appears to a be problem with the `angular-cli` creating an `app-root` reference in `index.html` file, while the Tour of Heroes tutorial entrypoint ts file refers instead to `my-app`. IMO the two should use the same naming convention since the Angular team have been recommending `angular-cli` as the best way to create a project.

Comment: Somewhat similar, just in case anybody facing this issue with webpack-dev-server (WDS) - I had built my app when selector was <app-root> and launched the app using WDS. Then I changed selector to <my-app> in my component and index.html. That is when I started getting above error. Problem was, index.html under 'dist' folder was not updated. I stopped WDS, built my app again and then launched app. Everything started working just fine!

Answer (score 31):

Things to do:

1. Go to **app.module.ts** (to main modules, in most cases this is a name)
2. Check if you have part "**boostrap**:" - if no add:

   `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` // where AppComponent is your main component
3. Check if it works now, if not - **go to AppComponent and check your selector**. It should be **same as tags in body in index.html**

so index.html should contain something like this:

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

where instead of `<app-root>` you should use selector from main AppComponent

4. If you are using your angular app in external website then you should consider using defer in headers for angular files

Comment: `<body>` tag fixed it

Comment: Thank You! It Solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Non of the above answers resolved my issue .This is how solve the same kind of error.
You shouldn't have more than one component as Bootstarp component .So, Bootstrap array should have only one component .By mistake I put 4 components in bootstrap array.I removed those 4 components from there and put in  entryComponents array(as shown in the code below).This helped me.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
AppComponent,
SanackBarBodyComponent,
SuccessNavBarComponent,
AlertNavBarComponent,
NormalNavBarComponent
],
entryComponents:[ 
SanackBarBodyComponent,
SuccessNavBarComponent,
AlertNavBarComponent,
NormalNavBarComponent
],

imports: [
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule
],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6):

I got same issue when I use Angular Universal. But it is because I am using `BrowserModule` in **main.node.ts**, the solution is

```
  imports: [
    UniversalModule,
    BrowserModule   // <- delete this will solve the issue
  ],
```

And check here for more info: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/542

Comment: This isn't true for the latest versions of Angular. These days BrowserModule replaces UniversalModule but an appId is passed as a parameter so that client and server can exchange. See here: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/83f659777a1f7914c357d5c0eb72705b04dc94ea/docs/angular2-universal-migration.md

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the angular2 / asp.net core template from here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ you might find replacing the last few lines of boot-client.ts with the following helps (and avoids a lot of scary looking console errors when HMR reloads your page):

```
const bootApplication = () => { platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule); };
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    window.onload = () => bootApplication();
    location.reload();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootApplication);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was updating an Angular 5.2 app to Angular 6.1 and run into similar issue. In this case the problem was that *index.html* file did not have `<body>` at all. It was instead included in the `my-app` component.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<my-app></my-app>
</html>
```

This used to work with Angular 5.2 (and earlier versions too) because in the generated *index.html* the script tags were placed at the end. After upgrade to 6.1 the script tags were instead placed in the beginning of the file (and I assume therefore executed before the `<my-app></my-app>` root element is actually present.

Solution was to move `<body>` into *index.html*. (It was originally placed in to the component because someone wanted to apply conditional classes to body element with `ngClass`.)

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I changed the bootstrap component from `AppComponent` to a new component. When you change it you need to change it in the main `index.html` as well. `index.html` should contain the bootstrap component.

For example, if you change the `app-component` to `app-login` in `app.module.ts` in the bootstrap section then you should update your `index.html` like this

```
<body>
  <app-login></app-login>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

When i create new component need to follow below steps to resolve the below issues.

Step-1- Create new comonent with `ng g c lakshya`.
Step-2- Under app lakshya folfer created with  4 files.
Step-3- Index.html need `<app-root></app-root>` to `<app-lakshya></app-lakshya>`
Step 4- app.Module.ts file change bootstrap: [AppComponent] to  bootstrap: [LakshyaComponent]

so above error resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the

> defer

Tag in your headers js-files.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: This answer works for majority of cases for this error. This really should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Django+Angular

I had a custom index.html, not the one generated by angular CLI.

I had this error because I placed the generated script files in the `<head>` section instead of at the end of the closing `</body>` tag (after the `<app-root></app-root>` tags)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is something wrong in index.html where the ' located file(most of the case is the root folder).

After fix it, everything runs as normal.

Answer (score 1):

sure you use app-routing module and must change the selector: 'my-app' to 'app-root' (file: app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts, if you have my-app in the bootstrap, comment or delete it.

bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    // my-app
  ]