# Angular 2 Heroes Tutorial error: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

I am following the Heroes tutorial at the angular official website.

I generated the project using CLI.

Everything works fine until in Part 6 Routing: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

I updated the code **before routing**, and the tutorial says:

> The app still runs and displays heroes.

But, I am getting the following error:

> The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

from the Chrome dev console.

I tried changing `app-root` to `my-app` in `index.html` or changing `my-app` to `app-root` in `app.component.ts`'s `selector` value. Nothing helped.

This is the 2nd time I am trying the tutorial from scratch during the past year, and yet I believe I am facing the same issue (don't quite remember what exact issue I had the last time, but gave up due to some error). This makes me think that something is wrong with the tutorial.

But then, when I google, I can't find anybody else who's having this issue. There are a few who are having

> my-app not matching any elements

issue, but not from the Heroes tutorial.

Anyone else who's tried the Heroes tutorial? Have you had this issue? I am stuck at this point and can't continue with this tutorial.

You want my code? as I said it is the same as it is given in the tutorial right before adding routing into the equation.

Thanks.

Update:

I said my code is the same as that in the tutorial, oh well, there are some differences: 1) I use templateUrl where the tutorial uses template, 2) I didn't use those big font h1, I am using div.

So the relevant code is here below, but this won't get you going unless you CLI'ed the project by following the tutorial because there are tons of other files in the project. I am curious, has anyone successfully followed through the entire tutorial without encountering any issue? If yes, then I might be doing something wrong, but otherwise, I am suspecting something is wrong with the tutorial.

```
//app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';  
}

//app.component.html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
    <my-heroes></my-heroes>
</div>

//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//hero-detail.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
   selector: 'hero-detail',
   templateUrl: 'hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
    @Input() hero: Hero;
}

//hero-detail.component.html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div>
    <div *ngIf="hero">
        <div>{{hero.name}} details</div>
        <div><label>id:</label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div><label>name:</label><input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" /></div>
    </div>    
</div>

//hero.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService { 
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
     return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

  getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return new Promise(resolve=> {
      setTimeout(()=>resolve(this.getHeroes()), 2000);
    });
  }
}

//hero.ts
export class Hero {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 }

//heroes.component.html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];  
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroesSlowly().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}

//mock-heroes.ts
import {Hero} from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
    {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
    {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
    {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
    {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
    {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
    {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
    {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
    {id: 19, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
    {id: 20, name: 'Magma'},
    {id: 21, name: 'Tornado'}   
  ];

//index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My NG App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-root></my-root>
</body>
</html>

//main.ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: How does your `AppComponent ` class looks like, are you declaring the selector like `@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'...` or what?

Comment: Yes, if you could post your index.html file contents and your AppComponent that would be helpful. That way we don't have to work through the tutorial to get to the same point you currently are. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35644123/4488121

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro: I've seen that one you linked. Looks similar, but not the same.

Comment: @DeborahK: I've updated the post with relevant code. You will need to CLI the heroes project and plugin my relevant files in order to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this:

```
<body>
  <my-root></my-root>
</body>
```

needs to be this:

```
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

In the index.html file.

And to answer your question, at ngConf in April they had a room for developers to work through the tutorial, which was just about full the day I was working the room. It appeared that they were all basically successful (with most of the difficulty in getting npm install to work on everyone's system.) But I have not been watching closely to know if that area of the docs have changed since then. (I'm on the doc team, but mostly work on the guide, not the tutorial).

Comment: Yep ^  OP - forgive me if you already know this -  but the selector is the html element that the compiler will look for to render your component. In the case of the root / app component, it will look for that element in your index.html file and it will bootstrap ("launch") the app when it finds it. If there is a mismatch - No app! You could name it anything, as long as they match up. So if the selector in your app component is  'bla-bla-bla', you just need to make sure in your index.html file you have  <bla-bla-bla></bla-bla-bla>     good luck!