# Why am I getting 'ERROR Error: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements' when it is in the dom?

Tags: angular

I have the following component...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    template: '<h1>Hellooooo Nurse</h1>'
})
export class TestComponent{}
```

and...

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js';
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {TestComponent} from "./TestComponent";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    bootstrap: [TestComponent],
    imports:[BrowserModule]
})
class Application{ }
export {Application}
```

finally...

```
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic()
const app = platform.bootstrapModule(Application)
export {app}
```

in my index.html I have...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="./out/ng-demo.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-component></ng-component>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run I get...

> ERROR Error: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements

I tried creating a custom element like...

```
constructor(private injector:Injector){}
ngDoBootstrap() {
    const element = createCustomElement(
        TestComponent,
        {
            injector: this.injector
        }
    )
    customElements.get('ng-component') ||
    customElements.define('ng-component', element, {});
}
```

But then I get...

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Application: (?).

Comment: as your `TestComponent` is the only being boostrapped, he's the one whom selector have to be included into the body tag of your index.html file. So you need to add a selector to this component and use this selector into the index.html file.

Comment: Looks like it is related to this...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644123/the-selector-my-app-did-not-match-any-elements

in terms of my dom not being loaded first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the same question [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644123/the-selector-my-app-did-not-match-any-elements). The solution was...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const platform = platformBrowserDynamic()
    const app = platform.bootstrapModule(Application)
});
```